# Яндекс карта вывести геокоординаты в виде город, улица дом

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

как вывести геокоординаты по текущему местоположению в виде город, улица дом

Answer (score 1):

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation,
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55, 34],
      zoom: 10
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

  // Сравним положение, вычисленное по ip пользователя и
  // положение, вычисленное средствами браузера.
  geolocation.get({
    provider: 'yandex',
    mapStateAutoApply: true
  }).then(function(result) {
    ymaps.geocode(result.geoObjects.position).then(function(res) {
      alert(res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text'));
    });
    // Красным цветом пометим положение, вычисленное через ip.
    result.geoObjects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redCircleIcon');
    result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.set({
      balloonContentBody: 'Мое местоположение'
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects);
  });

  geolocation.get({
    provider: 'browser',
    mapStateAutoApply: true
  }).then(function(result) {
    // Синим цветом пометим положение, полученное через браузер.
    // Если браузер не поддерживает эту функциональность, метка не будет добавлена на карту.
    ymaps.geocode(result.geoObjects.position).then(function(res) {
      alert(res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text'));
    });
    result.geoObjects.options.set('preset', 'islands#blueCircleIcon');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

*Исходники*:

- Тут пример получения местоположения - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation
- Тут пример получения информации - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode

Comment: Вы посмотрели приведённые ссылки? Покажите нам - как вывести геокоординаты по текущему местоположению.

Comment: Это понятно, а как их соединить? вот это я не понимаю

Comment: есть такой метод
 geolocation.get({
        provider: 'yandex',
        mapStateAutoApply: true
    }).then(function (result) {
        result.geoObjects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redCircleIcon');
        result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.set({
            balloonContentBody: 'Мое местоположение'
        });
        var firstGeoObject = result.geoObjects.get(0);
        var cit ="'" + firstGeoObject.getAddressLine() + " " +firstGeoObject.getPremise() +" "+firstGeoObject.getPremiseNumber() + "'";
        document.write(cit);
    });

Comment: Исправил ответ, дал пример кода